# cosine_similarity returns matrix instead of single value

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, cosine-distance

I am using below code to compute cosine similarity between the 2 vectors. It returns a matrix instead of a single value `0.8660254`.

> [[ 1.         0.8660254]
>
> [ 0.8660254  1.       ]]

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
vec1 = [1,1,0,1,1]
vec2 = [0,1,0,1,1]
print(cosine_similarity([vec1, vec2]))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) `cosine_similarity(X, Y=None, dense_output=True)` returns *an array with shape (n_samples_X, n_samples_Y)*. Your mistake is that you are passing [vec1, vec2] as the first input to the method. Also your vectors should be `numpy` arrays:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np
vec1 = np.array([[1,1,0,1,1]])
vec2 = np.array([[0,1,0,1,1]])
#print(cosine_similarity([vec1, vec2]))
print(cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2))
```

> X : ndarray or sparse array, shape: (n_samples_X, n_features)
>       Input data.

So you have to specify the dimension.

```
np.array([1, 2]).shape
```

has funny shape:

> (2, )

Answer (score 0):

```
vec1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
vec2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
print(cosine_similarity([vec1], [vec2]))
```

I passed the 2nd vec2 as Y and I got the output as a scalar.