# Calculating cosine similarity between 3D arrays using Python

Tags: python, cosine-distance, bert, matrix

I have two matrices with multiple columns and three rows each. I calculated the cosine similarity (sklearn) but it gives the result as a matrix. How can I obtain one single value?
The matrices are the embeddings of two words each, obtained from BERT.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26648/cosine-similarity-returns-matrix-instead-of-single-value), if it solves your problem

Comment: Already checked, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Your input matrices (with **3 rows** and **multiple columns**) are saying that there are **3 samples**, with **multiple attributes**. So the output you will get will be a 3x3 matrix, where each value is the similarity to one other sample (there are `3 x 3 = 9` such combinations)

If you were to print out the pairwise similarities in sparse format, then it might look closer to what you are after.

I have created two example matrices of random numbers that fits your description:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import sparse

a = np.random.random((3, 10))
b = np.random.random((3, 10))

# Create sparse matrices, which compute faster and give more understandable output
a_sparse, b_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(a), sparse.csr_matrix(b)

sim_sparse = cosine_similarity(a_sparse, b_sparse, dense_output=False)
print(sim_sparse)
```

Output:

```
  (0, 2)    0.7938732813430508
  (0, 1)    0.7575978172453429
  (0, 0)    0.7897664361147338
  (1, 2)    0.740418315571796
  (1, 1)    0.833981672896221
  (1, 0)    0.7184526671218405
  (2, 2)    0.8746293481677073
  (2, 1)    0.6456666045233884
  (2, 0)    0.7925289217609924
```

Hopefully this output makes it clearer, what you are actually getting as output.

Have a look here for a [**few more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat) on performance aspects, and the [**documentation on sparse matrices is here.**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html)

Comment: I'd like to explain the problem in a more precise manner. I am extracting embeddings from a pre-trained BERT model. These are sentence embeddings. But my requirement is to find the similarity between two words using this model. I passed two words - e.g. hi and hello, but I am getting a matrix as the cosine similarity output, whereas what is expected is a single value. Am I going wrong anywhere?